# Do waves accelerate?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

Typically we think of acceleration as a particulate property but a previous question on this forum got me thinking. If we think of a wave increasing its velocity by increasing its energy/frequency there must be a rate of change of velocity .... of the wave .... Even if the direction of propagation is changing it has to do so at a certain rate I assume?

I have not studied electrodynamics yet, but will look up anything that comes up so please just answer with whatever theory is needed.

Comment: Classical waves in inhomogeneous media can "accelerate", even thought it's not a good way of thinking about these kinds of problems.

Comment: Which previous question?

Comment: electromagnetic waves propagate with a constant $c$ speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, wave can accelerate. The electron matter wave in the atom is an example of a wave that keeps changing its propagating direction. However the stationary state condition of quantum mechanics requires such wave to form eigen-modes of the Hamiltonian, which would have a fixed and quantized energy.

Comment: thank you :) So if we were to for a moment assume the second half of your answer was not true, then the acceleration (by alteration of the direction of propagation) would also cause the energy to change, which would then obey electrodynamics and emit radiation? Of course this doesn't happen but just hypothetically speaking.... in essence: is it the changing of the waves energy that causes the emission of  radiation?

Comment: @JanetthePhysicist Yes, if the wave is not stationary, it will actually oscillate among different eigen-modes with a specific frequency determined by the pattern of the wave. In the presence of electromagnetic field, this oscillation will couple to the electromagnetic wave, and the energy will be release or absorbed in the form of radiation with the same frequency. That is why we can observe spectral lines with quantized frequencies in the atomic radiation.

Comment: The ground state wave function of an atom is perfectly stationary.

Comment: @CuriousOne Obviously you did not read the post carefully. We are talking about a generic excited state of the electron, but not its ground state. I do not see any inappropriateness in my answer. However if you feel that something is wrong, please discuss here and make edit to help improve the answer, but not rudely vote down.

Comment: @EverettYou: the quality of your explanation has nothing to do with the fact that the question was not even about quantum mechanics, as far as anybody can tell.